# Error using [Today] in Sharepoint filter

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter

I'm having issues creating a filtered view in a SharePoint list.  The filter should display any results with a Created date from "this week".  In my case, "this week" is from the previous Saturday through the upcoming Friday.

I get the error message "Filter value is not in a supported date format." when trying to create the filtered view.

Here are my filters:

Show the items when column

`Created`
`Is Greater than or Equal to`
`[Today]-WEEKDAY([Today])`

and when column

`Created`
`Is Less than or Equal to`
`[Today]-WEEKDAY([Today])+6`

What am I missing? And is it as simple as I'm guessing it probably is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use complex formula in Filters - you have to keep it simple like [Today]-30 for last 30 days.

The solution is to turn the problem on its head and add calculated columns to work out the start of the week and the end of the week then filter when the current date is between those dates (i.e. Start <= [Today] AND End >= [Today])

This post gives you more details - its based on the Current Calendar Month but the same technique can be sued for calendar week - see formula at bottom.

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think this answer will get me the results I need with a few workarounds.